# When I clean my solution then dll missing error comes in my asp.net app

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an app in asp.net in which I have added a .dll file. When I clean the project and then build the project the .dll is missing in the reference. What is the solution?

Comment: Where did you put the dll file in your project?

Comment: I understand you added it in the references section of the project but you have to reference a specific file.  What is the URI of the .dll file linked to in your references?

Comment: Set the property of the reference to be copied into the build directory.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in your reference properties you have "Copy Local" = True.

If it's false it will not make it into your Bin directory on build.

Comment: How can I check my reference properties?

Comment: You right click the reference and hit Properties. When you build your project does the dll appear in the appropriate bin folder?